# Finding the optimum result of an expensive process

Tags: optimization

I have an algorithm $A$ that takes parameters $\theta$ and returns a real number $x$: $A(\theta) = x$. I want to find the optimum value of $A(\theta)$ for values of $\theta$ within a fixed range. For example, if $\theta$ is a single real number, I might want to find $argmax_\theta A(\theta)$ where $0 \leq \theta \leq 1000$. In this example, I could simply compute the result for each value of $\theta$ within the range. If $\theta$ is instead a vector, I could run a grid search over the ranges of each parameter.

However, if this option is too cumbersome, for whatever reason, what are my options?

Comment: Is the output from A observed without variation (so a repeat would yield an identical $x$ each time)? Or would repeating the same inputs, $\theta$ lead $A(\theta)$ to yield different values? If the second situation is the case you have, you may want to look at *response surface methodology*. If the first, your question seems likely to be off-topic here.

Comment: @Glen_b, I'm interested in both cases; I'm not aware of the practical differences between these two situations (and I'd like to be). Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: If there's no variation, it's a pure optimization problem. If there's variation, then it becomes a statistical problem. The cost of evaluation means that it's not worth trying to be too "clever" about the optimization - simple approximations to the function (such as quadratic approximations) generally do about as well as can be afforded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function given by A has any structure at all, it will be a good idea to infer this structure from the points you've sampled. This could take a number of forms, for example, simple ones:

- Fit a least squares linear model to the data
- Fit a least squares convex quadratic model [example](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/exa_quad_fcn_cvx_min.html)

In those cases, you can always solve for the minimum of your current model by solving a constrained optimization problem. If the model is not that accurate at least you can sample values near the minimum of the model.

As well, there are plenty of probabilistic models/search frameworks that could incorporate a model into search. MIMIC (from a former professor of mine) [tutorial](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/tutorials/mimic-tutorial.pdf) would be just one such example.